# Resume of product query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the following schema table:

[image]

I have three activerecord models with their associations. I am struggling with a query which will show the following information for each product:
**Product Name, Money Total, Quantity Sold Total**

It should also take account on the status of the order that the product_line are associated with, which it should be equal to "successful".

I also want a second one query which it will show the above but it will have restriction based on the month (based on the orders.created_at column). For example if I want the sales for January of this product.
**Product Name, Total Money so far, Quantity total, Month**

I managed to create something but I think it isn't very optimized and I used ruby's group_by which it is doing many additional queries on the view. I would appreciate how you usually start thinking about creating a query like that.

**Update**

I think I almost managed to solve the first query and it is the following:

```
products = Product.joins(:product_lines).select("products.name, SUM(product_lines.quantity) as sum_amount, SUM(product_lines.quantity*products.price) as money_total"),group("products.id")
```

I tried to split each columns separately and find out how I could calculate it. I haven't take into account the order status though.

The associations are the following:

**ProbudtLine**

```
class ProductLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Product**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_lines
end
```

**Order**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :product_lines, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: can I see the ActiveRecord models & their associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.

**First query**:

```
@best_products_so_far = Product.joins(product_lines: :order)
                                          .select("products.*, SUM(product_lines.quantity) as amount_total, SUM(product_lines.quantity*products.price) as money_total")
                                          .where("orders.status = 'successful'")
                                          .group("products.id")
```

**Second query**:

```
@best_products_this_month = Product.joins(product_lines: :order)
                                          .select("products.*, SUM(product_lines.quantity) as amount_total, SUM(product_lines.quantity*products.price) as money_total")
                                          .where("orders.status = 'successful'")
                                          .where("extract(month from orders.completed_at) = ?", Date.today.strftime("%m"))
                                          .group("products.id")
```